# Long Table Realignment Help

Tags: tables, longtable

I have been able to make the long table, but right now it goes outside my pages. I can only see 2 full columns, a partial half of the 3rd column, and the 4th one is completely bleeding out of the page.
This is for a Paper and I can't share the full code because of that. But this is how I start it out, the table is all good, but I need help realigning it to fit my page. I would appreciate any advice!

```
\begin{longtable}{@{}|l|l|l|l|@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{X} &
  \textbf{X} &
  \textbf{X} &
  \textbf{Citation} \\* \midrule
\endhead
```

Comment: I would like for the longtable to be realigned to fit the page, right now the table goes out of the page and is not quite right.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided a reason for why the table's width exceeds `\textwidth`. I'll assume (hopefully correctly) that the reason is that you're not allowing automatic line-breaking in the columns. Moreover, I'll assume that allowing automatic line breaking will, in fact, remedy the situation as long as the column widths are set suitably.

If these assumptions are correct, I would like to suggest is that you load the [xltabular](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xltabular) package instead of the `longtable` package and replace

```
\begin{longtable}{@{}|l|l|l|l|@{}}
```

and

```
\end{longtable}
```

with

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ XXXX }
```

and

```
\end{xltabular}
```

respectively. Do note that `X` is *not* random filler stuff but a particular column type. The table's target or design width will be `\textwidth`.

Is this a useful starting point for you? Please advise.

---

The following code takes up the preceding ideas and provides a minimally compilable test document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % no full justification

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} LLL l @{}} % <-- the crucial new line

%% headers and footers

\caption{A four-column table} \\
\toprule
\textbf{X} & \textbf{Y} & \textbf{Z} & Ref. \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\tablename~\thetable, continued} \\[0.5ex]
\toprule
\textbf{X} & \textbf{Y} & \textbf{Z} & Ref. \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (continued on following page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table

a & b & c & d \\
e & f & g & h \\
i & j & k & l \\

\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Nerd - Did my answer help solve your formatting question. If so, please consider "accepting" it -- by clicking on the checkmark symbol placed to the left of the start of the answer. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for nice explanation in answer. Since OP so far didn't response on it, it is unclear (at list to me) what OP looking for. So I suggest to close question as  "Needs details or clarity".

Comment: @Zarko - I agree.